# look up this week number?

Tags: sql-server, week-number

I know how to look up this week number:

```
(SELECT DATEPART(wk, GETDATE()))
```

I need to know the syntax of getting the week number compare to another table:
SYNTAX:

```
SELECT     THISWEEK  -- WEEK NUMBER DATA
FROM       dbo.DATETABLE
WHERE THISWEEK  = (DATEPART(wk, GETDATE()))  -- THIS IS THE PART I AM NOT SURE.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the correct syntax. You have more than the necessary amount of parens, but it does no harm.

```
select distinct
    thisweek
from
    datetable
where
    thisweek = datepart(wk, getdate())
```

Is equivalent to saying:

```
select distinct
    thisweek
from
    datetable
where
    thisweek = 34 --8/18/09 is in the 34th week of 2009
```

Comment: Hi Eric, I only need results: THIS WEEK NUMBER.  It's correct syntax but the results are:  WEEK NUMBER DATA for the whole year.

Comment: Eric, I understand your logic; you are doing hard code. I need to use: GETDATE()

Comment: @Yonita: I changed the queries to only bring back the week number. Of course, this is really superfluous and too much overhead if you just need the week number, *unless* you're validating to make sure that week is in your date table.

Comment: you are right - I am doing validation.  Can you help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

This looks good to me.